# Powershell Folder monitor/batch execution

Tags: command-line, batch, powershell

I am new to Powershell. I have found a script that works with what I need, kind of.

What I am looking for is a script to monitor a folder for specific file names/types. Depending on the file name/type, I want it to execute a certain batch file to execute a command for a server utility.

How exactly would I achieve this.I found this script and added a invoke-item to launch a batfile one a file such as PDF lands in the folder. However, I need to filter it and have it launch a different bat file depending on the file name. What I currently have, it will invoke the bat file for each file that lands in the folder which I don't want. My knowedlge is minimal and I only know enough to be dangerous.

If XXXX.PDF, XXRX.PDF, XXLX.PDF hit the folder, I need it to know if XXXX.PDF lands, run XXXX.bat only. If XXRX.PDF lands run XXRX.BAT only, etc, etc.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "D:\XXXX\XXXX"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.PDF"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true 

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED

    $action = {Invoke-Item "D:\BATCH FILES\XXXXX.bat" -filter = "XXXXX.pdf"}    

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
    $created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
###    $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
###    $deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
###    $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: You should look at the help files for "Test-Path" and "If". Create your IF statement: if test-path = true, then perform some action (in this case you bat file).

Answer (score 1):

FileWatchers have quirks, [depending on how files are created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7792216/4424236):

> You may notice in certain situations that a single creation event
>   generates multiple Created events that are handled by your component.
>   For example, if you use a FileSystemWatcher component to monitor the
>   creation of new files in a directory, and then test it by using
>   Notepad to create a file, you may see two Created events generated
>   even though only a single file was created. This is because Notepad
>   performs multiple file system actions during the writing process.
>   Notepad writes to the disk in batches that create the content of the
>   file and then the file attributes. Other applications may perform in
>   the same manner. Because FileSystemWatcher monitors the operating
>   system activities, all events that these applications fire will be
>   picked up.
>
> Note: Notepad may also cause other interesting event generations. For
>   example, if you use the ChangeEventFilter to specify that you want to
>   watch only for attribute changes, and then you write to a file in the
>   directory you are watching using Notepad, you will raise an event .
>   This is because Notepad updates the Archived attribute for the file
>   during this operation.

So in your case I would go with plain directory comparing. Here is the script that will monitor directory for changes and run files. Save this script as `MonitorAndExecute.ps1`. It accepts following arguments:

- **Path**: *folder to monitor. If not specified, the current directory is used.*
- **Filter**: *file extension to match. Default is `*`, i.e., match all files.*
- **Run**: *file extension to run, when new file is found. Default is `bat`.*
- **Recurse**: *recurse directories or not. Default is false.*
- **Interval**: *time in seconds to sleep between folder scan. Default is `5` seconds.*
- **Verbose**: *script will tell you what's going on via `Write-Verbose` messages.*

Example (run from the PowerShell console).

Monitor `*.pdf` files in the folder `D:\XXXX\XXXX`, recurse, if the new file is found, run file with the same base name and extension `*.bat`, be verbose:

```powershell
.\MonitorAndExecute.ps1 -Path 'D:\XXXX\XXXX' -Filter '*.pdf' -Run 'bat' -Recurse -Interval 10 -Verbose
```

`MonitorAndExecute.ps1` script:

```powershell
Param
(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({
        if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Container))
        {
            throw "Input folder doesn't exist: $_"
        }
        $true
    })]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Path = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).Path,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$Filter = '*',

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$Run = 'bat',

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [switch]$Recurse,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [int]$Interval = 5
)

# Scriptblock that gets list of files
$GetFileSet = {Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse:$Recurse | Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer)}}

Write-Verbose 'Getting initial list of files'
$OldFileSet = @(. $GetFileSet)
do
{
    Write-Verbose 'Getting new list of files'
    $NewFileSet = @(. $GetFileSet)

    Write-Verbose 'Comaparing two lists using file name and creation date'
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $OldFileSet -DifferenceObject $NewFileSet -Property Name, CreationTime -PassThru |
        # Select only new files
        Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } |
            # For each new file...
            ForEach-Object {
                Write-Verbose "Processing new file: $($_.FullName)"
                # Generate name for file to run
                $FileToRun = (Join-Path -Path (Split-Path -LiteralPath $_.FullName) -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + ".$Run"))

                # If file to run exists
                if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $FileToRun -PathType Leaf)
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Running file: $FileToRun"
                    &$FileToRun
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose "File to run not found: $FileToRun"
                }
            }

    Write-Verbose 'Setting current list of files as old for the next loop'
    $OldFileSet = $NewFileSet

    Write-Verbose "Sleeping for $Interval seconds..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $Interval
}
while($true)
```

Comment: What a pity, spot on answer and it's neither accepted neither upvoted... shame... Thanks for the answer helped me out.